How we can give access of a case to predefined case teams
After creating Case Roles and Predefined Case Teams, I can't see any option to Assign the Case to the predefined case team.

Create Case Assignment Rules:

In the Quick Find box, type "Case Assignment Rules" and select it.
Create a new rule or edit an existing one.

Define Rule Entries:

Add rule entries that specify the criteria for assigning cases to
predefined case teams. For example, you can set criteria based on
case origin, priority, or any other field.
In the "Assign to" section, select "Predefined Case Team" and choose
the appropriate predefined case team from the list.

Activate the Rule:

Ensure that the assignment rule is active to be applied to incoming
cases.

Note: If you need to dynamically assign new members to a predefined case team via code, you can use the CaseTeamTemplate and CaseTeamTemplateMember objects in Apex.
